# "Мне спасение" как "моё спасение" - возможно?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Единственное мне спасение – у каждого художника свой почерк.

(Это автор пытается вспомнить создателя шедевра.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы пропустила: воспринимается как эллиптическое *Единственное мне (есть, существует, ниспослано) спасение – у каждого художника свой почерк.*

Это же внутренний монолог? Там, по-моему, возможны такие конструкции.